# Twilio validateRequest on Cloud Functions fails in prod

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, twilio

I have a NodeJS function deployed using firebase-functions. I'm trying to validate  the request sent from the Twilio API using a signed header (see here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-security)

It works locally when I setup a proxy for the Twilio to connect to, but once it is deployed on prod, it no longer works;  it returns early and sends me the 403 as intended.

```javascript
exports.reply = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let isValid = true
  const twilioSignature = req.headers['x-twilio-signature']
  const url = `https://${region}-${projectId}.cloudfunctions.net/reply`

  // Only validate that requests came from Twilio when the function has been
  // deployed to production.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    isValid = twilio.validateRequest(
      config.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN,
      twilioSignature,
      url,
      req.params
    )

    console.log(`Token: ${config.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN}`)
    console.log(`Region: ${region}`)
    console.log(`projectId: ${projectId}`)
    console.log(`Signature: ${twilioSignature}`)
    console.log(`url: ${url}`)
    console.log(`Params: ${req.params}`)
    console.log(isValid)
  }

  // Halt early if the request was not sent from Twilio
  if (!isValid) {
    res
      .type('text/plain')
      .status(403)
      .send('Twilio Request Validation Failed.')
      .end()
    return
  }

  // Prepare a response to the SMS message
  const response = new MessagingResponse()

  // Add text to the response
  response.message('Hello from Cloud Functions!')

  // Send the response
  res.status(200).type('text/xml').end(response.toString())
})
```

The console logs looks like it returns the right values, but the twilio.validateRequest() function still somehow returns false. Why?

## Things I've deduced:

1. Env variables - can't be as it goes into the .status(403) fn after checking with NODE_ENV
2. Cloud Functions Users - allUsers is enabled meaning it is open to public access

Comment: Since you are retrieving the token from the `config` and you saw that the value appears to be correct in the logging, you could be going through the same issue as described in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51384714/12857703). Try hardcoding it, as a test, to check if it works.

Comment: @RafaelLemos No go. I even tried using a `===` comparison between a hardcoded string value of the token and the value being pulled from the `config`, it gave out as true but the `validateRequest()` function still outputs `false`.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No. We actually just went back to this problem once again for a new project, and are trying new things.

Comment: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/650 @xander

Comment: got it - thank you :)

Comment: Were you able to actually fix it @Xander